# Changing the stack size and LD_LIBRARY_PATH using a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I would like to be able to have a rule inside my makefile that a changes the stack size and that appends to LD_LIBRARY_FILE the current directory.
In the shell I can just do:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$(pwd)

ulimit -s SOME_NUMBER

Is there way to make a rule inside a makefile that is equivalent to running this two commands and will update the environment variables after the makefile is run?

Comment: You can set up the rule to affect child processes of the make, but not to affect the calling shell

Answer (score 1):

You can link the executables with `-z stack-size=VALUE` or `-rpath`, which might have a similar effect.

You could push the command characters to the TTY layer and hope that the shell will execute them, but that is a bit nasty.  The makefile could also compile a program which does the job using `ptrace`, but that would be very ugly as well.

Answer (score 0):

No

A child process in bash cannot effect the environment of the calling shell (as @mpez pointed out).   This is done on purpose to avoid some security holes.   It's possible to export the commands to change the environment variable to a script, and run that script after you run make (which can be automated through another script), but make itself cannot effect the environment of the calling shell.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How would I do this through a script?

Comment: Have make create a script (say `postmake.sh`).   which would contain something along the linkes of `export VAR1=x; export VAR2=y ...`, and then have another script `domake` which basically does `make $@ && eval ./postmake.sh`.   (you need to use `eval` rather than call the script directly).